# Communication sites, Asset Library not available?

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, modern-team-site, asseturlselector

Is it correct that in Modern Communication sites, the app `Asset library` is not there even if you turn on the `Team Collaboration Lists` feature?

I understand Microsoft wants to force you to use Stream but the asset library was a useful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset library app is available once you activate the `Video and Rich Media` site collection feature. It is not part of the Team collaboration lists feature.

To activate it:

1) Go to your Site collection > Site Settings

2) Manage Site collection features

3) Activate the `Video and Rich media` feature.

[image]

Once you activate it, you will be able to view the Asset library template in Add an app section.

Reference  - [Use the video and rich media feature in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-video-and-rich-media-feature-in-sharepoint-4be4b56f-65b1-46e2-9e68-a6bd2d491b88)